# Reading each string from a .csv file

Tags: python

for this assignment, I have to read information from a passwords.csv file. Here is the content below.

```
March2021 iudj8&neB09 MyDogWo0f mv3m959
ven1vid1v1c1Iulius 123456789 abcdefgcijk What#ItN0w
windsofchange HelloMyNameIs 4584208 4586300
Anniv&0629 BDay@1955 BigBadW0d! !Rf0donotcare
R85r!4L145 S3att!eWa SONameHere Abc!23
```

In my program, this is what I have.

```
userFile = input("Enter the full pathway file: ")
openFile = open(userFile,"r")
readFile = openFile.read()

newList = []
for line in readFile:
    newList.append(line.strip())
    print(newList)
```

The output is this.

```
['M']
['M', 'a']
['M', 'a', 'r']
['M', 'a', 'r', 'c']
['M', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'h']
['M', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'h', '2']
['M', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'h', '2', '0']
['M', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'h', '2', '0', '2']
```

How can I make it copy the whole string instead of the letter repeated over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the file to read each line and add words:

```
userFile = input("Enter the full pathway file: ")

newList = []
with open(userFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        newList += line.split()

print(newList)
```

Comment: How can I make it where it only prints the final line once?

Comment: Just remove the print call from the for loop. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you read the file into `readFile` and then iterate that string. Strings iterate character by character so you see the list growing by one character on each print. You should do the iteration on the file, which reads line by line.

But its better to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module in the standard library. Here, I just used the default "excel" rules but changed the separator from comma to space. If any of your passwords.csv cells contain properly escaped spaces, they will be processed properly here.

```
import csv

userFile = input("Enter the full pathway file: ")
with  open(userFile, newline="") as file:
    newList = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=" "))
print(newList)
```

Python is "batteries included" - might as well use what is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a new line after every word (I think) but in your loop

```py
for line in readFile:
    newList.append(line.strip())
    print(newList)
```

You're making a new line after every letter. To make the array, then print the line outside of the loop.

```py
for line in readFile:
    newList.append(line.strip())
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because read the entire file into a single string, you're iterating over the character is it. To split that string up into a list of separate lines, all you need to do it call the [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method.

```
with open(userFile) as openFile:
    newList = openFile.read().splitlines()

print(newList)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is that you have the print statement inside of the for loop.
So hopefully

```
for line in readFile:
    newList.append(line.strip())
print(newList)
```

should work.
If this isn't what you meant, just tell me.